# dll Library functions not found in matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, dll, loadlibrary

I have a `dll` library and it's Header file but when I use `loadlibrary` on matlab it Returns No functions;

`[notfound,warnings] = loadlibrary('MDF4Reader.dll','CMdf4Reader.h')`

http://www.turbolab.de/mdf_libf.htm (a link for the library I want to import)

Comment: Is the library in your path/folder?

Comment: Did you build the DLL yourself and did you remember to copy all header files as needed to a folder in your Matlab path.

Comment: @AnderBiguri yes it is

Comment: @Jørgen I didn't build it myself I took it from the link attached to the question

Comment: It looks like a COM DLL, at least the header `CMdf4Reader.h`indicates this. I tried to register it (`regsvr32 MDF4Reader.dll`) as such, but that failed. You need a _proper_ header file in order to load the file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late but I think this might help. I had the same issue with a very simple c++ function. What solved it for me was to change the header file to include "#ifdef __cplusplus". Here goes the example header file:

```
// my header file
#ifndef MYC
#define MYC

#ifdef MYPROJECT_LIB_API
#undef MYPROJECT_LIB_API
#endif
#define MYPROJECT_LIB_API

#ifdef __cplusplus
#define MYPROJECT_LIB_API_EXTERN_C extern "C"  MYPROJECT_LIB_API
#else
#define MYPROJECT_LIB_API_EXTERN_C extern  MYPROJECT_LIB_API
#endif

MYPROJECT_LIB_API_EXTERN_C int cSum(int a,int b);

#endif
```

With this my functions are now seen in matlab.

Comment: Indeed, functions must use the C call convention, not C++ or any other. For many C++ functions, you can’t just change the call convention, because they use classes as input types.